# Android: How to use a ViewPager + action bar tab correctly in a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listMainMenu"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/color_list_mainmenu_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_mainmenu_selector_background"
    android:background="@color/color_list_mainmenu_background"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So in my MainActivity class I can show my main menu and I can show a new Fragment:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    String title = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new WorkoutStoreFragment();
            title = getString(R.string.mainmenu_item_workout);
            break;
        ....
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frameContainer, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        this.listMainMenu.setItemChecked(position, true);
        this.listMainMenu.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(title);
        this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(this.listMainMenu);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

But in my WorkoutStoreFragment class (extend v4.support.Fragment) I want to use a viewPager with a TabPageIndicator class to show some different other Fragments. But it doesn't work.

In general, my view architecture is it correct ?

Thanks by advance guys!

Comment: Is [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) what you want?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I have a fragment, and I would like from it, to have some tabs to show some other fragments.